# Azure SignalR Context Within Constructor

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

Is there a way to get the user Id within a AzureSignalR Process?
Like below I want to get that User Id and if I dont use AzureSignalR I can get it through the HttpContext but in the case of AzureSignalR it seems that only in the actual methods themselves i cant get that ID meaning I cant do anything in my app since i need that User ID

```
public class BaseHub : Hub
{

    public BaseHub()
    {
        var userId = this.Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "user_id")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2#windows-authentication).